# Splitting a Value JSON

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a json file, I would like to split a value into parts based on seeing [..] and |..|. If they are seen at least 2 times. By split, I mean taking the one line from time and  separating the string if it sees 2 or more [..] or |..| of these characters.

```
[
     {
         "Action":"Walk",
         "Time":"1 hour [c] 2 hour [dog] 1 hour [p]",
     },
     {
         "Action":"Pet",
         "Time":"1 hour [cat] 2 hour |d|",
       
     },
     {
         "Action":"F",
         "Time":"1 hour [cat]",
       
     },
]
```

Desired Result

```
[
     {
         "Action":"Walk",
         "Time":[
               "1 hour [c]",
               "2 hour [dog]",
                "1 hour [p]"   ],
     },
     {
         "Action":"Pet",
         "Time":[
            "1 hour [cat]", 
            "2 hour |d|"
                        ],
       
     },
     {
         "Action":"F",
         "Time":"1 hour [cat]",
       
     },
]
```

Here is my code:

```
with open(filenames,"r") as f:
        data=json.load(f)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "split a value into parts".

Comment: Split Value as in we have the key value pair "Time":"1 hour [c] 2 hour [dog] 1 hour [p]", It is originally one value but I want this to be many values for "Time":["1 hour [c]","2 hour [dog]","1 hour [p]"]

Comment: Seems to be solvable with some regex and using re.split on each `data[i]["Time"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex can solve that easily, but is quite hard to read.
I recommend you checking out the cheatsheet on [regexr](https://regexr.com) and possibly look into the regex documentation of [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

But here you go - that code should do what you asked for:

```
import re

with open(filenames, "rw") as f:
    data=json.load(f)
    for action in data:
        action["Time"] = [
            time_part.strip()
            for time_part 
            in re.findall(r".*?(?:(?:\[.*?\])|(?:\|.*?\|))", action["Time"])
        ]
        if len(action["Time"]) == 1: # when only a single action was done don't store it as an array
            action["Time"] = action["Time"][0]
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The regex when removing special character escape (like `\[` to `[`), non-capturing groups (these `(:?`) and lazy matching (regex matches as much chars as possible by default. Using `*?` is called lazy matching) - just so it's easier to understand:

This is basically the logic used above: `.*([.*] OR |.*|)`

Comment: @user18774110 
I just recognised: This expression will set `action["Time"]` to `[]` when the string doesn't contain any `[]` or `||` - be aware of that.